# Best way of Laying out menu screen IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I currently have a menu screen that is presented as the root view on loading the application.  Selecting the new Character option causes a modal view to be presented with character specific features (such as name of character, height etc). Once the user clicks continue, the navigation controller is presented modally and from then on the navigation controller, controls the progression of views.  Would you say this is a bad practice of modal views?

Would it be better if I used the navigation controller from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely opinion based and use case specific but I generally prefer to present detail views in a modal view and the rest of the navigation of the app in a navigation controller. This allows the user to easily navigate back and forth throughout the app while modal views popup only for details of a specific item.